# ! File ended while scanning use of \textbf

Tags: errors, a0poster

I'm new to LaTeX and am building a math research poster. I keep getting the error message:

```
! File ended while scanning use of \textbf .<inserted text>\par<> ProjectionMatricesPoster.texI suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing meto read past where you wanted me to stop.I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious,you'd better type `E' or `X' now and fix your file.! Emergency stop.<> ProjectionMatricesPoster.tex (job aborted, no legal \end found)Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:14333 strings out of 493921289176 string characters out of 3144873323480 words of memory out of 300000017396 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+2000007005 words of font info for 21 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000841 hyphenation exceptions out of 819155i,3n,56p,447b,177s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

and it says it occurs in Line 1:

```
\documentclass[a0,landscape]{a0poster}

\usepackage{multicol}
\columnsep=100pt
\columnseprule=3pt

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{times}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{figures/}}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[font=small, labelfont=bf]{caption}

\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[b]{0.55\linewidth}
\veryHuge \color{NavyBlue} \textbf{Title}\\
\Huge\textbf{subtitle}\\[1cm]
\Huge\textbf{Authors}\\
\end{minipage}
```

I put the whole error message in one line as it appeared. I realize that is difficult to read however, so let me know if you want me to change that or delete any parts of it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Without wishing to sound patronising, this is a very good first post, particularly from someone who seems entirely new to the Stackexchange network. However, I think it might be helpful if you could provide a **complete** MWE http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that and provide the full text of the error message you're getting. If you include a few lines before the error message, it should show us which file LaTeX was reading when it encountered the error - it may not be your .tex file

Comment: Not just helpful. It is actually essential since the code you've posted contains no errors in the use of `\textbf{}` at all. So we can only say that the error must lie elsewhere, which may not be incredibly helpful, unfortunately.

Comment: Do you get the error message with the code you just added? I ask you because, after adding the missing `\end{document}` I don't get any errors (just a warning).

Comment: I tried that just now and it worked for me as well! But I started the document again after this bit of code, and it only outputs the part I posted on here.

Comment: I am going to keep ending and beginning the document between chunks of code to see where this is happening.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because error fixed by OP in a part of the document not shown.